# Сделать блокировку на редактирование word документа на PHP

Tags: php, ms-word

В общем использую библиотеку \PhpOffice\PhpWord которая позволяет мне генерировать нужный word документ используя подготовленный шаблон. Все работает. Но после генерации и скачивания документа он редактируется. Нужно это запретить. Есть какие-либо идеи кто пользовался этой библиотекой? У меня с ней пока опыта мало. Но пока инфы во всемогущем  GOOGLE не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поставить пароль на редактирование;

```
<?php 
require_once("vendor/autoload.php"); 

// Input file
$name = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
$name="sample";
$source = __DIR__ . "/{$name}.docx";

$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($source);

// Add Password Protection For editing 
$documentProtection = $phpWord->getSettings()->getDocumentProtection();
$documentProtection->setEditing(PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\DocProtect::READ_ONLY);
$documentProtection->setPassword('123456');

// Write the output file

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64114769/15331960